# Python - bs4, check if class has a value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have been playing around with bs4 abit and I found an issue that I cant managed to pass. What I want to do is that if there is a value in a class then we pass and if there is no value in class then we continue.

Situation one:

```
<option class="disabled RevealButton" value="1_120">
                            Overflow                        </option>


<option class="disabled RevealButton" value="1_121">
                            Stack                       </option>


<option class="disabled RevealButton" value="1_122">
                            !!!                        </option>
```

Situation 2

```
<option class="" value="1_120">
                            Overflow                        </option>


<option class="" value="1_121">
                            Stack                       </option>


<option class="" value="1_122">
                            !!!                        </option>
```

What I have done right now is:

```
try:
    select_tags = bs4.find('select', {'autocomplete': 'off'})
except Exception:
    select_tags = []

for select_tag select_tags:

    print(select_tag)
```

and what it does right now is that its printing either the first situation or second.

What I want for output is following:

if class contains *disabled RevealButton* then we just pass and continue the loop.

if class **DOESN'T** contains *'disabled RevealButton'* then we print out **select_tag**

I have no clue what I can do to be able to solve my problem!

Comment: `select` tag has no attribute `autocomplete` and I can't see this tag in your html, do you mean `option` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if an element has `disabled` and `RevealButton` classes, you could use the [dictionary-like interface](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) of BeautifulSoup elements (`Tag` instances):

```
"disabled" in element["class"] and "RevealButton" in element["class"]
```

Note: you need to apply this on the option element.

Note that `class` is a special [multi-valued attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes) and its value is a list.

---

Another option (no pun intended) would be to look for option element with both classes:

```
for select_tag in select_tags:
    if select_tag.select("option.disabled.RevealButton"):
        continue

    print(select_tag)
```

Here, `option.disabled.RevealButton` is a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that would match `option` elements having both `disabled` and `RevealButton` classes.

Comment: Oh okey! So I tried to apply the second option where you have ``if select_tag.select("option.disabled.RevealButton"):`` but that just tells me `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'select'`

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere cause you have this `select_tags = bs4.find('select', {'autocomplete': 'off'})` which locates a single element and when you iterate over the element it iterates over all the children including text nodes (navigable strings). Did you mean `find_all()`?

Comment: Ohhh! Yeah, I think I forgot to add the find_all! It seems to work now I believe